# Rails geocoder dynamically set language and units

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to achieve so that the language will be set dynamically before geocoding and/or reverse geocoding occurs, right now, I set the language in an initializer of the app.

```
Geocoder.configure(

    :units => :km,
    :language => :en
)
```

I would like it so that the language would be set dynamically, for example:

```
Geocoder.configure(

    :units => :km,
    :language => lambda {|something| I18n.locale}
)
```

does anyone knows how this can be achieved?

Comment: `:language => I18n.locale.parameterize.underscore.to_sym` not working?

Comment: which geo-coder functionality are you using? most of them have a units parameter. and what is language for? never seen that option.

Comment: @phoet :language returns the results in a certain language, english, deutch, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[looking at the code](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/21775d13841d3a8433a987b79db7bf202e35159a/lib/geocoder/lookups/google.rb#L43-L59) it seems like this is not possible.

what you can do though, is re-configure on every call to google

```
Geocoder.configure(language: :en)
Geocoder.search("Nantes, France")
```

this kind of sucks. i think the api should allow you to pass that in as a parameter like `:unit`.

i created a pull-request for this feature https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/pull/654

UPDATE

so it actually is possible:

```
Geocoder.search("Nantes, France", params: {language: :fr})
```

plus there is another change incoming that supporting this https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/pull/655